# Если запускать view pager из FragmentActivity - слетает Материал Дизайн у кнопок, почему?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-material

Приложение запускается с `setContentView(R.layout.view_pager);` из FragmentActivity, которое, в свою очередь, в манифесте прописано первым при запуске. В pager'е 3 страницы, у них свои Fragment классы (не знаю хорошее или "новое" ли это решение..), в Fragment классе 3ей страницы прописан Intent переход в MainActivity, в котором `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`. Так вот проблема, в pager'e у кнопок слетел материал дизайн, но если прописать `setContentView(R.layout.view_pager);` в MainActivity, то всё ок.. Почему?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zTzg.png (как слетело)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoFGQ.png (как описал 3ий Fragment класс и Intent переход)
Модераторы, почему кликабельные слова не работают, это у меня руки кривые?))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение: изменил наследование FragmentActivity с `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity`на `AppCompatActivity`
Дизайн подтянулся, в принципе логично, материал дизайн то унаследовался от AppCompat)
Кому нужно, полный код FragmentActivity

```
public class FragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_pager);

    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager) {
        super(supportFragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 1:
                return new Fragment2();
            case 2:
                return new Fragment3();
            default:
                return new Fragment1();
        }
    }
}
```